# Autosubmit a language dropdow in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization

I'm wondering how to get a dropdown that switches the page's language to work. I currently have the following:

```
<%= select('locale', 'id', %w(English Español Italiano 日本語 한국어), :onchange => "this.form.submit()") %>
```

Any idea how I can get this to switch the page's locale?
I am currently passing the locale via the params hash.

Comment: Does the form submit? Otherwise, check the JS, because this doesn't sound like Rails has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems:

1. You're trying to submit a select box..... but *where* does it submit to?
2. How are you managing the languages on your page?

--

When *submitting* with JS, you have to remember that it needs to *somewhere* to submit to.

Like a `<form>`'s `action` attribute, your JS needs a location to send the submit request. This is normally handled with a form, but can also be manually inputted with Ajax.

You may wish to use this:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("change", "select", function(e) {
   $.ajax({
      url: "your/url",
      data: $(this).value(),
      success: function(data) { ... },
      error: function(data) { ... }
   });
});
```

This will take the inputted value of the `select` box and send the data to a preformatted route in your Rails app. This leads nicely onto my second question -- how you get the language to remain in the app...

-

Regardless of your structure, you'll need to give your Rails app a way to determine the language you have selected.

If only to set a [session variable](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session), you have to pass your data through to your Rails controller.

To do this, you first need to ensure you have the *routes* and then the *controller action* required to handle the request:

```
#config/routes.rb
post :language, to: "application#language"

#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   def language
      session[:language] = params[:language] #-> this needs to be refactored
   end
end
```

You'll then be able to pass back some response or command to invoke the language change on the page.

Although setting the language in the backend, as described above, may seem tedious, doing so will give you the ability to set the entire language parameter for the site -- IE if you wanted to use it for currency etc, it will be available in all the actions you need.

Hope this helps.